# HTML emails with rowspan are not getting displayed correctly

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I've a html email message with table as follows

[image]

This has the following html code

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-69vs{font-size:100%;font-family:serif !important;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-69vs">Name</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">City</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Place</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e" rowspan="3">acc</td>
    <td class="tg-031e" rowspan="2">CS</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">SJC</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">WDC</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">2<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">NS</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">WDC</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">acc2</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">NP</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">CA<br></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I send this as a HTML email, the rowspans are not getting applied correctly. I've seen in some pages asking to avoid using rowspans and instead to use nested tables. I tried with converting into nested tables but I'm not getting the desired table. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Note:
The rowspan will vary depends upon the city and place

**Edited:**

For eg,
I tried with a table with single row with rowspan of 5.
The code is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<style type='text/css'>
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;}
.tg .tg-4eph{background-color:#f9f9f9;}
.tg .tg-4epg{vertical-align:middle;}
.tg .tg-alert{background-color:#f38630;}
.tg .tg-header{background-color:#f38630;font-weight:bold;}
.tg .tg-bsv2{background-color:#f0f0f0;font-weight:bold; color: #000;text-align:center}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-header">Name<br></th>
    <th class="tg-header">City</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Place</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Price<br></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="tg-4eph" rowspan=5>Blue</td>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-4eph" rowspan=4>NS</td>
          <tr>
   <td class="tg-4eph">NW</td>
            <td></td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
   <td class="tg-4eph">CA</td>
            <td></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
   <td class="tg-4eph">SJC</td>
   <td></td>
      </tr>
    
    <tr>
   <td class="tg-4eph">WDC</td>
   <td></td>
          </tr>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="tg-4eph" rowspan=1>CS</td>
    <td class="tg-4eph">SJC</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Which gives me the result as follows

[image]

I've given the rowspan as 5 in the code. But in the output table the rowspan is only 3. What is wrong in the above example code?

The desire output should be

[image]

Comment: Your html code gives me the same result as the image (except the vertical align), what is your desired result ?

Comment: @Utkarsh: See my edited answer above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rowspan is not the most reliable way, but it can still be used fairly effectively.  Your first example seemed to work fine (tested in EmailonAcid) once I wrapped in DOCTYPE and HTML/HEAD/BODY tags. Please remember though that your stylesheet will not work in Gmail and to one degree or another in other email clients as well. It is always best to inline styles.

The issue with your second example was that there was validation errors. Please see below, which works in almost all email clients (tested in EOA) - with the exception of the stylesheet support issue.

Please let me know any specific clients you were seeing issues in and I can try and check them out specifically.

See below for corrected code on second example (please note the non-breaking space code inside the TDs. Some email clients will delete a completely empty TD, so by adding this in, it keeps the rendering more consistent.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<style type='text/css'>
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;}
.tg .tg-4eph{background-color:#f9f9f9;}
.tg .tg-4epg{vertical-align:middle;}
.tg .tg-alert{background-color:#f38630;}
.tg .tg-header{background-color:#f38630;font-weight:bold;}
.tg .tg-bsv2{background-color:#f0f0f0;font-weight:bold; color: #000;text-align:center}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-header">Name<br></th>
    <th class="tg-header">City</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Place</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Price<br></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="tg-4eph" rowspan="5">Blue</td>
        <td class="tg-4eph" rowspan="4">NS</td>
        <td class="tg-4eph">NW</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="tg-4eph">CA</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="tg-4eph">SJC</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="tg-4eph">WDC</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

       <tr>
          <td class="tg-4eph">CS</td>
          <td class="tg-4eph">SJC</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS, use vertical-align:middle for certain cell.

Please change from 
td class="tg-031e" rowspan="3">acc


to

td class="tg-031e" rowspan="3" style="vertical-align:middle;">acc

Comment: I think OP is asking about rowspan not the vertical align of elements. Isn't it ?

Comment: OP is asking about Email HTML not correct. Rowspan will not work correctly in email.